# simple join query working in localhost but not in server?

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-error-1054

The following query runs well on localhost and returns rows but when it is executed in server it returns error...

The  error shown is

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'hc.id' in 'on clause'
```

What the issue?

```
select 
hd.holiday_id,h.same_date, h.holiday, hd.date 
from holiday_dates as hd 
join holidays as h on hd.holiday_id=hc.id 
join holiday_countries as hc on hc.holiday_id=h.id and hc.country_id=c.id 
join countries as c 
where 
c.name='india' and hd.year='2010'
```

My table structure is 
**countries**

```
'id', 'int(11)', '', 'PRI', '', 'auto_increment'
'name', 'varchar(80)', 'YES', '', '', ''
```

**holidays**

```
'id', 'int(11)', '', 'PRI', '', 'auto_increment'
'holiday', 'varchar(90)', 'YES', '', '', ''
'same_date', 'tinyint(1)', 'YES', '', '', ''
'religions', 'varchar(50)', '', '', '', ''
'season', 'enum('Winter','Spring','Summer','Autumn')', '', '', 'Winter', ''
'rate', 'int(2)', '', '', '0', ''
```

**holiday_countries**

```
'id', 'int(11)', '', 'PRI', '', 'auto_increment'
'holiday_id', 'int(11)', '', '', '0', ''
'country_id', 'int(11)', '', '', '0', ''
'link', 'varchar(40)', '', '', '', ''
```

**holiday_dates**

```
'holiday_id', 'int(11)', 'YES', 'MUL', '', '' //  this refers to the holiday_id from holiday_countries table
'year', 'varchar(4)', 'YES', '', '', ''
'date', 'date', '', '', '0000-00-00', ''
```

Comment: "join holidays as h on hd.holiday_id=hc.id"
Look carefully to this line.

Comment: It works fine on localhost, local mysql version is 4.1.10 and the server mysql version is 5.1.52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order you have your joins is messed up, it looks like it was a typo at the end of my 6th line

```
    select hd.holiday_id
         , h.same_date
         , h.holiday
         , hd.date 
      from holiday_dates as hd 
      join holidays as h on hd.holiday_id = h.id 
      join holiday_countries as hc on hc.holiday_id = h.id 
      join countries as c on hc.country_id = c.id 
     where c.name='india'
       and hd.year='2010'
```

Fixed, missed the and c.id at the end of line 7

A little more information for you:
These errors are being thrown because you are referencing fields in a table that have not yet been joined and had an alias made.

so back to your original query:

```
    select hd.holiday_id
         , h.same_date
         , h.holiday
         , hd.date 
      from holiday_dates as hd
      join holidays as h on hd.holiday_id=hc.id
      join holiday_countries as hc on hc.holiday_id=h.id and hc.country_id=c.id 
      join countries as c 
     where c.name='india'
       and hd.year='2010'
```

Your original error was because you reference the table hc on line 6, but join it and make an alias at line 7.  The second error was because you reference the table c on line 7, but join and make an alias on line 8.

Edit:

This doesn't make much logical sense to me without the table structure, but try this one:

```
   select hd.holiday_id
         , h.same_date
         , h.holiday
         , hd.date 
      from holidays as h
      join holiday_countries as hc on hc.holiday_id = h.id 
      join holiday_dates as hd on hd.holiday_id = hc.id 
      join countries as c on hc.country_id = c.id 
     where c.name='india'
       and hd.year='2010'
```

Enjoy,

Comment: Now it shows Unknown column 'c.id' in 'on clause' error for your query

Comment: I updated my answer to fix the problem you brought up and add some more info for you.

Comment: Thanks for a fine explanation on reference but that query almost worked but with a wrong set of data.. The dates are wrong in the output.. Something went wrong with the joining

Comment: I can't see what would be wrong with the query.  Please post some more details about your table structure with a few example rows so we can better help you.

Comment: Added one more try to my answer.

Comment: I've edited my question with more data on tbl structure and thanks for your patience and helping out

Comment: I added another option for your query

Comment: Your last query done that well.. Thanks mate... I think i've completely study the tbl reference first..

Comment: I've one more doubt.. If i want to get all the data for more than one year for example, 2010 , 2011, 2012 etc.. My desired output will have the columns like holiday_id, same_date, holiday, date(2010),date(2011), date(2012) .. Is that possible using a single query??